# How to sum largest $n$ values in a range in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of values and I need to sum the largest 10 values (in a row).  I found this but I can't figure it out/get it to work:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/A5jiMqkRLYE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let's say you want to sum the 10 highest values of the range E2:EP
then try:

```
=sumif(E2:P2, ">="&large(E2:P2,10))
```

and see if that works ?

EDIT: Maybe this is a better option ? This will only sum the 10 outputted by the array_constrain. Will only work in the new google sheets, though..

```
=sum(array_constrain(sort(transpose($A3:$O3), 1, 0), 10 ,1))
```

Can you see if this works ?

Comment: I don't think this works.  Let's say I have 15 values and they're all the same -- then this will sum all 15 values (when I only want 10 summed).  The context to this is I am assigning grades and need to take only the top 10 quizzes.

Comment: Oh yes.. that's correct. Think I misunderstood your question. But can you explain how you want to take the 'top10' out of 15 when all 15 values are the same ? (Based on what criteria ?) Would it be possible to share a spreadsheet with some sample data and the expected outcome ?

Comment: I edited my previous answer with an alternative formula.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks!  (If there are ties, it doesn't matter which values are chosen since they give the same sum)

Comment: Exactly ! Sorry for not getting it the first time .. :-)

Comment: "=sum(array_constrain(sort($A3:$A50, 1, 0), 10 ,1))"  worked for me because my data was in a column already.  Also, this formula works if you want the top 10, but you only have 8 values.  The first formula just returns 0. (I was looking at this for a Social Security sheet, and you won't always have all the values needed, which is fine)

Answer (score 0):

This works in old google sheets too:

sum(query(sort(transpose($A3:$O3), 1, false), "select * limit 10"))

Transpose puts the data in a column, sort sorts the data in a descending order and then query selects first 10 numbers.

Unfortunately, replacing sort with "order by" in a query statement does not work, because you can not reference a column in a range returned by transpose.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sortn`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) function seems to be just what you need.

From the documentation linked above, it "[r]eturns the first n items in a data set after performing a sort." The data set does not have to be sorted. It takes a bunch of optional parameters as it can sort on multiple columns.

```
SORTN(range, [n], [display_ties_mode], [sort_column1, is_ascending1], ...)
```

The interesting ones for your case are `n`, `sort_column1`, and `is_ascending1`. Specifically, your required formula would be

```
sum(sortn(transpose(A3:O3), 10, 0, 1, false)))
```

Some notes:

- This assumes your data in A3:O3. You can replace it with your range.
- `transpose` converts the data row to a data column as required by `sortn`.
- `10` is `n`, indicating the number of values that you require.
- `0` is the value for `display_ties_mode`. We are ignoring this value.
- `1` is the value of `sort_column1`, telling that we want to sort the first column (after transpose).
- `false` tells `sortn` to sort descending and thus pick the largest values. The default is to pick the smallest.